# How do spirit generator damage modifiers stack in Diablo 3 ? Additively or multiplicatively?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

If my current spirit level is giving me, let's say, 200% damage bonus on my spirit generator thanks to my Shenlong set bonus, will depth diggers bump this up to 300% or double it to 400% ? What about damage increase that applies to all damage, such as the bonus you get from Shenlong when at max spirit ?

Comment: Checking atm, please wait.

Comment: Also you mean Static Charge by Shenlong right? edit: you don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Picture from the game]

As you can see from the picture, it clearly states that it is "additional" and not "multiplicatively".

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. I wasn't really sure because some builds talk about depth diggers as "doubling" my damage. I guess they're not as critical as I though in a high attack speed shenlong build.

Comment: Incidentally, what about other percentage based multipliers but that apply to "all damage", such as the shenlong bonus you get at max spirit ? I'm guessing that takes my "damage increase by skills" from 0% to 100%, and that *would* actually double my spirit generator's damage. Am I correct in thinking that ?

Comment: @ticster I think that you are correct.